# How do I use Glide to display images?

Tags: android, image, android-glide

I tried to load an image from the url below:

```
 https://leixing.fswear.local/design?type=frame&action=query_img&imageuuid=5ab8b4fc18859b6e3c5a0e6d
```

But it showed me the error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException(java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.)
java.io.FileNotFoundException(No content provider: https:/...
```

Is it because that the url i made my imageview load is a get url so no suffix like ***.jpg*** something ?

*And is this the correct way to display a image from server* ? **Do i need actually download images into local storage or keep it like this everytime request server to display** ? *Or is there anyway recommend*

Comment: the provided image url is not working

Comment: idk but i have tested the url is working in my chrome

Comment: Your given url is not a image url

Comment: yes, so how can i do to display the images.. do i have to download it manually ? Thank you for your precious replies

Comment: `... is this the correct way ...?` **which** way? You didn't provide a single line of code!

Comment: ah, i mean i didn't download file only with using something like this   `.apply(new RequestOptions()
                            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .error(R.drawable.qq)
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .priority(Priority.HIGH))      `

Comment: so `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)` is the way to handle network images right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is your image is hosted on a server which dns is private.thats why android couldn’t connect to server.To access this private server you need a security certificate of that dns.Ask your server guy to give you this certificate and then install this certificate on your device then also you have to configure your wifi to access this dns

Comment: Yeah. I think you are  on the point. And can you provider a working example for certificate in android with retrofit... I did many searching and the only one "Unsafe certificate is working for me "... I have two files for ".pem" ".p12"

Comment: oh, wait ... is that mean i need to add the cer. into glide something

Comment: Thank you so much for the help ! Hope you have a really nice day there

Comment: I still am trying to find something for the cer.

Comment: the extension of this certificate is .cert which is used by android to connect with unsafe private dns server.You will find security option on device settings and there’s a way to add certificate.So first ask your server guy who manages this server to make dns certificate for you then install it on above way and then add two dns to the device’s connected wifi to mark this dns known.Thats it.

Comment: Idk fully understand... I have the cer. files and i think i need to use the ".p12" one for which it's nothing to do with the server right? or maybe not (i'm noob),  I want my app read the certificate file and build a ok http client to enable the retrofit client request some https

Comment: try installing it on device as i told.may be there’s different types of extension of certificate.So i think it will be installed

Comment: and you mean i can't install it by code

Comment: yeap it need to installed on device security settings

Comment: try to understand there are two types of dns public dns which can be accessed by anything as this is public and another private dns which can’t be accessed every one. for accessing this private dns server you must have needed dns certificate which generally developed by guys who manages this server.the error you got ssl cert error is caused for that. android couldn’t find this dns on public

Comment: thank you so much ! you are amazing !  I feel convinced after reading your comments and i think for image i can use http as well so i'll try that